# Build my own map and interact with it with zoom and clickable areas

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to build a screen with map of a theater, and user can interact with zoom in/out and choose seats on map.
When user touch on a seat, the icon of seat is changed.
Is there some lib/component to build my own map with touch areas? Or some good idea to use Android API to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a webview, to create the panning effect, then create (locally), a file with the logic you want, such as drawings/bitmaps/whatever of the images you want, and onClick events for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the `SurfaceView` API.

It provides you with an easy to use abstraction for drawing on a canvas. You can use it to render your theater image and intercept touch events on it. However, zoom in and zoom out are not supported out of the box, so you should implement them separately.

Another thing you can do is show your image in an `ImageView` and use scaling to implement the zoom in/zoom out, but then intercepting the exact touch position can get a little tricky.